# SQL Server select from multiple tables stored in a column or list

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Because it is too complicated to solve this problem without real data, I will try to add some:

```
               |       tables 1       |      table 2        |   ...   |     table n
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
columns_name:  |  name | B | C | D    |  name | B | C | D   |   ...   |    name | B | C | D
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
column_content:|  John | ...          |  Ben  | ...         |   ...   |    John| ...
```

The objective is to extract the rows in the N tables where name = 'John'.

Where we already have a table called [table_names] with the n tables names stored in the column [column_table_name].

Now we want to do something like that:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM (SELECT [table_name]
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
WHERE [name] = 'Jonh'
```

Tables names are dynamic and thus unknown until we run the information_schema.tables query.

This final query is giving me an error. Any clue about how to use multiple stored tables names in a subquery?

Comment: You can't - object names cannot be parameterized like this. You must use dynamic sql. This is a very **complicated** approach - you should get some direction and help from your giant consulting firm. And I'll point out that your derived table (which has no alias) has no column named 'name' - the only column it contains is [table_name]. It appears you intended to select all tables (the name only) that contain the column named "name". Unfortunately, your query doesn't do that at all. If something else, then using meta-data doesn't seem to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alias your subquery in order to reference it. Plus name should be table_name

```
SELECT [table_name]
FROM (SELECT [table_name]
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES) AS X
WHERE [table_name] = 'Jonh'
```